# Is there any better alternative to busy waiting in this case?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, thread-synchronization

I have a `Manager` class that encapsulates a (rather) low-level facility (e.g. database) and serves as a factory for `Worker` instances, which

- use `Manager`'s underlying facility (database)
- reference `Manager` from each instance
- are used concurrently
- can launch asynchronous tasks which refer to the database (in some detached thread).

The `Manager` also has a `shutdown()` method that closes the database connection. To ensure that the connection will stay alive if there are any running threads launched by any `worker` (i.e. not to close database connection until there are still workers using it), I currently have something like this:

```
Manager mgr   = new Manager(database);
Worker worker = mgr.newWorker(arg0, arg1, arg2);

worker.runHeavyComputation();
```

where `runHeavyComputation` is defined like this:

```
void runHeavyComputation() {
    executor.execute(() -> {
        myManager.tellTaskLaunched();
        doSomethingWithDatabase();
        myManager.tellTaskFinished();
    });
}
```

where `Manager#tellTaskLaunched()` and `Manager#tellTaskLaunched()` are defined like this:

```
void tellTaskLaunched() {
    taskCounter.incrementAndGet();
}

void tellTaskFinished() {
    taskCounter.decrementAndGet();
}
```

and `Manager#shutdown()` looks like this:

```
void shutdown() {
    while (taskCounter.get() > 0) {}
    databaseConnection.close();
    database.shutdown()
}
```

I understand that this is a kinda lengthy introduction for such a simple question, but since I have encountered anti-busy-waiting statements almost in every book or post I've read, it occurs to me that there might be some alternatives to the simple solution I provide here, so I'd like to hear your opinions.

Note that since the `shutdown()` is likely to be called once per application lifecycle (or whatever it is they call a single long run), it isn't really a performance issue. However, I still would change it if something better comes up.

P.S. Note as well that although I said "your opinions", it's not really an opinion-*based* question :)

Comment: You can check if shutdown was called inside tellTaskFinished(), if so and counter is 0 - close connection.

Comment: @BobTheBuilder, do you think it's OK to mix the logic of tackling with connections with a simple task accounting that is happening inside `tellTaskFinished()` now?

Comment: Looks OK to me. It's just like firing "task-ended" event, which manager can use both for monitoring and closing the connection if needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is ALWAYS a better alternative to busy-waiting, at anything above the OS level.

See, for example, the wait and notify operations on Thread.

Comment: Awesome, how should I use them?